# boot2docker ssh apache-kylin windows7 source ambari-functions ambari-functions ERROR : line 11: syntax error: bad function name

Tags: windows-7-x64, boot2docker, ambari, kylin

Here is my script (boot2docker ssh).

```
docker pull sequenceiq/kylin
curl -O https://raw.githubusercontent.com/sequenceiq/docker-kylin/master/ambari-functions
source ambari-functions
```

And the returned error :

```
-sh: ambari-functions: line 11: syntax error: bad function name
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ambari-functions
rename run-command to run_command 
rename amb-clean to amb_clean
etc